# Mysql stored procedure not working in java

Tags: java, mysql

My mysql procedure is working fine, but somtimes it gets hanged, when i call it from java class
My mysql procedure is as follows

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `expense`.`user_updation`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `user_updation`(IN `I_user_id` VARCHAR(10), IN `I_USER_PASSWORD` VARCHAR(200), OUT `o_error_flag` VARCHAR(1), OUT `o_error_msg` VARCHAR(100), OUT `o_user_email` VARCHAR(50))
begin 
declare v_user_password1 varchar(200);
declare v_user_password2 varchar(200);
declare v_user_password3 varchar(200);
declare v_user_password4 varchar(200);
declare v_user_password varchar(200); 
declare v_user_email varchar(50); 
declare v_rec_status varchar(50);
 DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK;
        SET O_ERROR_FLAG = 'E';
        SET O_ERROR_MSG = 'UNKNOWN EXCEPTION IN SQL EXECUTION, CONTACT SYSTEM ADMINISTRATOR...';
    END;
 DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR 1205
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK; 
        SET O_ERROR_FLAG = 'E';
        SET O_ERROR_MSG = 'RECH_AUTHOR-RECORD IS LOCKED BY SOME OTHER USER, TRY AFTER SOME TIME';
    END;
    select STATUS into v_rec_status from user_m where USER_NAME=I_user_id;
    IF v_rec_status='X'
    THEN
    SET O_ERROR_FLAG = 'E';
    SET O_ERROR_MSG='USER IS INACTIVE IN SYSTEM';
ELSE
    SET AUTOCOMMIT=0;
    SET O_ERROR_FLAG = 'S';
    SET O_ERROR_MSG = 'SUCCESSFULLY';
    
select EMAIL_ID,password,USER_LAST_PASSWORD_1,USER_LAST_PASSWORD_2,USER_LAST_PASSWORD_3,USER_LAST_PASSWORD_4
INTO v_user_email,v_user_password,v_user_password1,v_user_password2,v_user_password3,v_user_password4 from user_m  where user_NAME=I_user_id limit 1;
SET o_USER_EMAIL=v_user_email;
update user_m set
        PASSWORD=I_USER_PASSWORD,   
        USER_LAST_PASSWORD_1=v_user_password,
        USER_LAST_PASSWORD_2=v_user_password1,
        USER_LAST_PASSWORD_3=v_user_password2,
        USER_LAST_PASSWORD_4=v_user_password3,
        USER_LAST_PASSWORD_5=v_user_password4,
        LAST_PASSWORD_DATE=Date(now()),
        ACCOUNT_STATUS='U',
                FORCED_PASSWORD_FLAG='Y',
                PASS_COUNT=0
where user_name=I_user_id ;
END IF;
end$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Java Class is

```
 public String setpassword(Procedurecall pro,String userid, String pass) throws SQLException
     {
         System.out.println(userid);
         System.out.println(pass);
        
        try { Connection connection;
          connection = template.getDataSource().getConnection();
          CallableStatement callableStatement = connection.prepareCall("{call user_updation(?, ?, ?,?,?)}");
          callableStatement.setString(1, userid);
          callableStatement.setString(2, pass);
          callableStatement.registerOutParameter(3, Types.VARCHAR);
          callableStatement.registerOutParameter(4, Types.VARCHAR);
          callableStatement.registerOutParameter(5, Types.VARCHAR);
          callableStatement.executeUpdate();
          String is_error = callableStatement.getString(3);
          String msg = callableStatement.getString(4);
          String email = callableStatement.getString(5);
          pro.setIs_error(is_error);
          pro.setMsg(msg);
          pro.setEmail(email);
          
          System.out.println("-------------------------Procedure return status "+is_error+"-------------------- Message "+msg);
          return is_error;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("===========================Internal Server Error==========" +e);
            return "400";
        }
     }
```

while running java code, no errors are displayed, no updates are done. procedure isnt working.
So i tried calling procedure directly.

```
call user_updation('shah1234','passwordisgood',@f,@m,@e);
select @f,@m,@e;
```

the error message is

```
RECH_AUTHOR-RECORD IS LOCKED BY SOME OTHER USER, TRY AFTER SOME TIME
```

The error is actually

```
Lock wait timeout exceeded. Try restarting transaction.
```

And also if i try to update any other table, i get the same error, its seems i cant use any DML query.
On using
`SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_rollback_on_timeout';`
i get `OFF`. i think the solution is to turn it on, i am using wampp, i checked mysql.ini. i cant find the variable there

Comment: Use `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;` to see what's causing a lock

Comment: the result is type->Innodb, but name and status are empty

Comment: on using `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_rollback_on_timeout';` i get OFF. i think the solution is to turn it on, i am using wampp, i checked mysql.ini. i cant find the variable there

Comment: Now i restarted the server, again calling the procedure didnt worked, so i executed `commit` many times, now procedure is working only when called directly, if i call it from java again, the problem will again start

Comment: You have a `SET AUTOCOMMIT=0;` without a commit/ autocmmit=1 in your procedure. Unless you commit somewhere else, this will eventually be rolled back / might not be visible in other sessions / will lock rows until commit/rollback, ... This might explain (some of) the observed behaviour.